# Is there a way to fix - error TS7016: "Coul not find declaration file for module '@angular/compiler'"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, compiler-errors

I added SignalR to my Angular Frontend, after that there was -error TS7016 displayed.

import { ViewCompiler } from '@angular/compiler';

I tried: npm i --save-dev @types/angular__compiler

Answer (score 0):

`npm i -D @angular/compiler` should do the trick.

But *Module '"@angular/compiler"' has no exported member 'ViewCompiler'.*